# With CoreData, if I have an @dynamic property, can I override its getter just like it was @synthesized? (Lazy Instantiation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Using CoreData I created an entity, then I subclassed it into its own file, where it has the @propertys, then it has the @dynamic parts in the .m file.

When I want something to have a certain value if it's never been set, I always use lazy instantiation, like follows:

```
- (NSString *)preview {
    if ([self.body length] < 200) {
        _preview = self.body;
    }
    else {
        _preview = [self.body substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 200)];
    }

    return _preview;
}
```

But how do I do this with @dynamic properties? If I do the same thing, it says _preview is an undeclared property, but it's in the .h file. What do I do different to lazy instantiate it?

Comment: It says `_preview` is an undeclared _indentifier_, because you don't have a variable with that name. `@synthesize` creates the variable; `@dynamic` does not.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One standard method is to define `preview` as a *transient attribute* in the Core Data model (so that the value is not actually stored in the database), and implement a custom getter method. In your case it would look like:

```
- (NSString *)preview
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"preview"];
    NSString *preview = [self primitiveValueForKey:@"preview"];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"preview"];
    if (preview == nil) {
        if ([self.body length] < 200) {
            preview = self.body;
        } else {
            preview = [self.body substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 200)];
        }
        [self setPrimitiveValue:preview forKey:@"preview"];
    }
    return preview;
}
```

(You can provide custom getter, setter methods for @dynamic properties. However, Core Data
properties are not simply backed up by instance variables. That is the reason why you cannot 
access `_preview`.)

If you need the `preview` to be re-calculated if the `body` attribute changes, then you
must also implement a custom setter method for `body` that sets `preview` back to `nil`.

For more information, read [Non-Standard Persistent Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001919-SW1) in the "Core Data Programming Guide".

*Update:* The current version of the Core Data Programming Guide does
not contain that chapter anymore. You can find an archived version
from the [Way Back Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20150908004746/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdNSAttributes.html). Of course this has to be taken with
a grain of salt since it is not part of the official documentation
anymore.

Comment: Is all that is required to do is use that method? Or must I do something in the CoreData file?

Comment: @user212541: That should be all. You only have to mark the preview attribute as transient in the Core Data model editor.

Comment: How exactly does it duplicate the data?

Comment: Sorry, misspoke. I apparently misread the question. I was thinking that the two pieces of data were identical and being accessed from both the `body` property and the `preview` property. @Martin is right. That'll teach me for answering SO questions at 2am. deleting the original comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @tapi: No problem, I'll delete my replies.

Comment: @Downvoter: Would you care to leave a comment? Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: you should change :[self setPrimitiveValueForKey:@"preview"]; by             [self setPrimitiveValue:preview forKey:@"preview"]; in order to make this code work.

Comment: The  Non-Standard Persistent Attributes document is a dead link. I have seen countless references to this document, and I think it would be so helpful to have it to help deal with questions such as this.

Comment: @SAHM: Yes, unfortunately Apple removed several chapters from the Core Data Programming Guide with their recent updates (you might want to file a bug report at Apple!). I have added a link to an archived version to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

[See documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506728-primitivevalueforkey) on using `primitiveValueForKey:`

basically:

```
@dynamic name;

- (NSString *)name
{
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *myName = [self primitiveName];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"name"];
    return myName;
}

- (void)setName:(NSString *)newName
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveName:newName];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
}
```